# Turning on "show pointer" breaks mirrored screen. How to turn off without phone screen

Tags: adb, broken-screen, android-10

I am trying to help a friend who's screen broke on their Huawei P30. The screen is dead-dead. No touch, no light, nothing.

So I tried to connect an external screen to it, an voila, I have a screen. I even have a mouse and keyboard working. However, I want to copy the contents of the phone onto the computer, and nothing is showing up on the computer when I plug it in. So I tried to get ADB to help me.

ADB is not trusted, or something along those lines. So I go back to the screen, and turn on developer mode, and try to change settings to hopefully bypass the notification asking to give permission. Nothing works, I keep trying new settings.

This is where I mess up. Apparently there is a bug or something, because when you turn on (and I have no idea why I did this) "Show Pointer" the external display goes black with a grey bar at the top theoretically showing the pointer X and Y coordinates, etc.

If I reboot the device I see the home screen for 0.5 to 3 seconds before it reverts back to the black screen. If in this time, I click on the settings icon, it immediately goes to black.

Question: Is there a way, without access to the screen of a device to:

1. get ADB to work without it been an authorized device (I'm guessing not), or
2. turn off pointer location somehow using ADB or similar method, or
3. navigate the menus of the phone with a keyboard only, no mouse, no clicking, just keystrokes, so I can disable this blind (using another phone or video to know how many times to press down, for example)?

Any advice at all would be great. Since they already have a new phone, I don't want to have to pay to replace the screen, but that is last resort (which I hope would work).

Comment: Before Google acquired the company that developed Android, the whole system was designed for a non-touch display. From that time all Android commands have keyboard shortcuts. Therefore option 3 is realistic unless you device manufacturer has destroyed them while modifying the Andorid OS. My suggestion would be to use a Bluetooth keyboard and try to authorize adb blind.

Comment: Any tips on what terms to search for to find that? I'm coming up empty when i search. (read: full of spam ideas not relating to what I'm actually searching.)

Comment: I would search for `Android keyboard shortcuts` and e.g. end up here https://www.howtogeek.com/175267/the-htg-guide-to-using-a-bluetooth-keyboard-with-your-android-device/

Comment: Unfortunately that HowToGeek link focuses on shortcuts within apps or creating , and not how to navigate around in Android. :-( I tried searching for android navigation using keyboard, but they are all either related to the developer software, or specific apps in Android. I fear this is only going to be resolved by replacing the screen...